# JSON Output Missing } after property list. (line 19, file "Code")

Tags: json, output

I tried implementing the code from Google Developers (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5kaYpRJIqo @ 1:32)

But I seem to get the "**Missing } after property list. (line 19, file "Code")**" Error (latlng: [values[i][1], values[i][2]],)

This is my complete Code:

```
var SPREADSHEET_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

var SHEET_NAME = 'Data';

function doGet(request) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var cities = [];

for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
{
  var city = {
    name: values[i][0]
    latlng: [values[i][1], values[i][2]],
    population: values[i][3] 
  };
cities.push(city);
}

var json = Utilities.jsonStringify(cities);

if (request && request.parameters) {
  var call back = request.parameters.jsonp;
  if (callback) {
    json = callback + '(' + json + ')'; 
}

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(json).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

How can I get this code to work? Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` character, I believe it should be just before you `return` line at the bottom of you code, it is the closing brace for the `if (request && request.parameters) {` line.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error free code: http://jsfiddle.net/HrvG7/

Check comments that were reported as errors on the fiddle

```
var SPREADSHEET_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

var SHEET_NAME = 'Data';

function doGet(request) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();
    var cities = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        var city = {
            name: values[i][0], //comma was missing
            latlng: [values[i][1], values[i][2]],
            population: values[i][3]
        };
        cities.push(city);
    }

    var json = Utilities.jsonStringify(cities);

    if (request && request.parameters) {
        var callback = request.parameters.jsonp; //there was a space between call and back
        if (callback) {
            json = callback + '(' + json + ')';
        }
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(json).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, my Code is now Error free and my map is also running on android. But the markers from Google Drive still won't display on the map! I completed every step from the tutorial. Maybe the script above isn't complete? Do I need to add function testDoGet() {
  var request = {parameters: {jsonp: 'callback'}};
  var results = doGet(request);
  Logger.log(results.getContent());
} ???

Comment: Seems like a different issue than posted here.